# Ironpython Spotfire: How to add (Column Names) and (none) in Trellis expression

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, trellis

I'm writing an IronPython script within my Spotfire dashboard and I'm facing a problem. Goal of the script is: If a document property is TRUE, show a trellis with panels on column names. If the property is FALSE, do not show a trellis.
See below the part of the code where I currently get an error, because the way I write "(Column Names)" (and none as well) is incorrect. What is the syntax for this?

[image]

Comment: Update: I found the expression for Column Names: "<[Axis.Default.Names]>". However, I'm still looking for the expression (none).

Comment: "<>" should work for none